# Python explanation of a code

Tags: python

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x:f(g(x))

def thrice(f):
    return compose(f, compose(f, f))

def repeated(f, n):
    if n == 0:
        return identity
    else:
        return compose(f, repeated(f, n - 1))

def sq(x): return x**2
```

1) `print(thrice(thrice)(sq)(1))`

2) `print(thrice(thrice(sq)(2))`

Can anyone explain to me why the first function returns 1 and the second function does not work?
I was thinking thrice(thrice)(sq) will give me sq∘sq∘..... 27 times, so sq(1) is 1^27=1, is that correct? 
 thanks.

Comment: This looks like obfuscated rubbish.

Comment: (2) has a syntax error. A closing parenthesis is missing. Also, `repeated` is never used, why include it into the question?

Comment: In Python readability counts. That code counts up to ... 0.

Comment: What result are you expecting from the second function, exactly?

Comment: @coldspped - This is what `functional programming` looks like in Python ;).

Comment: `def repeated(f, n):` what is this for?

Comment: I'm required to explain how i get the answers from the function(if any). the answer for the first one is 1 when i execute it in python, but i did not get any output for the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thrice(thrice)(sq)(x)` is an extremely fast growing function:

```
thrice(thrice)(sq)(1.0000009)
#2.890634480354213e+52
thrice(thrice)(sq)(1.000001)
#1.9497974384856317e+58
```

When you apply it to a floating point number, it quickly overflows:

```
thrice(thrice)(sq)(1.000006)
# OverflowError: (34, 'Numerical result out of range')
```

**Edited (thanks to @KarlKnechtel)** However, Python implements arbitrary-precision *integer* numbers. When you apply the function to an integer number (say, `thrice(thrice)(sq)(2)`), the interpreter calculates the *precise* answer and then attemps to print it, which, with 40,403,562 decimal places, takes enormous time.

Comment: The result should be 2^(2^27). It doesn't actually take very long on my machine to compute this value (either by OP's method or more directly), but *formatting it for printing* would take extremely long.

Comment: so for the first case, it is 1^(2^27) = 1?

Comment: Correct. 1^N is always 1.

Comment: i see. Thanks for all of your help :)